# Select component to move component below once it's opened

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

behavior : Currently when selected option is other, then the input field is shows up, however, when i click on select again it covers the input field

expected : Once clicked on select option other input field shows up however when  clicking on select again it would move that input field down.

```
  <Select value={reason || undefined} showArrow={true}
                                placeholder={'Please select reason here'}
                                onChange={this.handleReasonChange}
                                style={{width: 300}}>
                            {reasonData.map(d => <Option key={d.value}>{t(d.text)}</Option>)}
                        </Select>
                        <OtherReasonInput onChange={this.handleOtherInputChange}
                                          reason={reason}
                                          otherReason={otherReason}/>
                    </div>
```

Trying to achieve it with styled.div but not sure how to throw an argument so its either true or false

```
 const StyledMyPart = styled.div.attrs({
    className: "modal-select",
    id: 'model-select'
})`
  &.modal-select-true div:last-child {
    position: relative !important;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question 100%, but here is my suggestion for you

```
<div>
   <div className={`artjom-select-${!!reason}`} id="artjom-select-container">
     <Select
       value={reason}
       showArrow={true}
       placeholder={"Please select reason here"}
       onChange={this.handleReasonChange}
       style={{ width: 300 }}
       getPopupContainer={() => document.getElementById("artjom-select-container")}
     >
       {reasonData.map(d => <Option key={d.value}>{t(d.text)}</Option>)}
     </Select>
   </div>
   <OtherReasonInput 
        onChange={this.handleOtherInputChange}
        reason={reason}
        otherReason={otherReason}/>
</div>
```

```css
.artjom-select-true div:last-child {
  position: relative !important;
}
```

Comment: that does the job i just need some modification to be done, thank you for the idea.

Comment: can that also be achieved used styled.div ?

Comment: I don't see why not

Comment: edited my question , if you mind kindly have a look

Comment: I guess, that I would do something like:
```
const StyledMyPart = styled.div.attrs({
    id: 'model-select'
})`
  & div:last-child {
    position: ${withValue ? 'relative' : 'absolute' } !important;
  }
`;
```

```
<StyledMyPart withValue={!!reason}>
    ...
</StyledMyPart>
```

Comment: Yeh that makes sense but for some reason i get undefined  on withValue prop